# FontFamily : Text disapears in TextView in KitKat

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, fonts

I am using fontFamily for custom font , but on KitKat the text disappears in textviews and button. I have separate files for api 26 and other for below. Following is code for <26 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/calibri"/>
    <font app:fontStyle="italic" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/calibri_italic" />
</font-family>

following is textview : 
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/field_number"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
     android:layout_weight="5"
     android:fontFamily="@font/calibiri_font"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:hint="3xxxxxxxxx"
     android:inputType="number"
     android:maxLength="15"
     android:maxLines="1"
     android:scrollHorizontally="true"
     android:textColor="@color/black"
     android:textSize="17sp"
     app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDarkGrey"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/field_countrycode"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/field_countrycode"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/field_countrycode"
     android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
```

I cant understand the issue as every thing is according to dcumentions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution for this problem. We need to make separate fort.xml files for >=v26  and 1 for

1- font/calibri_fort.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/calibri" />
    <font
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/calibri_italic" />
</font-family>
```

2- font-v26//calibri_fort.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <font
            android:fontStyle="normal"
            android:fontWeight="400"
            android:font="@font/calibri" />
        <font
            android:fontStyle="italic"
            android:fontWeight="400"
            android:font="@font/calibri_italic" />
    </font-family>
```